# Adding RSpec coverage for a method with if/else logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

So I am fairly new to RSpec and Rails and I've been trying to learn RSpec as much as possible and I am really struggling with implementing coverage for methods that contain logic in them.

The app that I am practicing with uses coverage percentages to make sure I am properly covering the code I am implementing and I am missing coverage on the following method:

```
def initialize_business
  businesses.each do |business|
    if business.type == 'Restaurant'
      @business_type = Business::Restaurant.new(json_directory: 'restaurant.json')
    elsif business.type = 'Bar'
      @business_type = Business::Bar.new(json_directory: 'bar.json')
    else
      @business_type = Business::Other.new(json_directory: 'other_business.json')
    end
  end
  business_type = @business_type
  initialize_business_creator(business_type)
end
```

My initial attempt at providing coverage (left out the other unrelated specs) but I struggled to even implement any coverage as I'm too new to RSpec:

```
describe '#initialize_business' do
    subject do
      described_class.new([business], business_sample_file).
      initialize_business_creator
    end

    it 'assigns a value to @business_type' do
      expect(assigns(@business_type)).to_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

I'm just looking for some help and/or guidance on how to implement specs for a method like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to create scenarios to test the branches of your code (`if`,
> `elsif`, `else`)

What you can do is, you can [`mock`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) the method which is returning the `type` to get your desired results.

For example if you want to test that your `if` condition is evaluated and the code in that branch is run successfully.

You can do something like this:

```rb
describe '#initialize_business' do
    subject do
      described_class.new([business], business_sample_file).
      initialize_business_creator
    end

    it 'assigns a value to @business_type' do
      expect(assigns(@business_type)).to_not be_nil
    end
    
    context "when business type is 'Restaurant'" do
        before { allow_any_instance_of(Business).to receive(:type).and_return "Restaurant"
    end

    it "should create data from restaurant.json" do
        //here you can write expectations for your code inside if statement

    end
  end
end
```

The line:

> allow_any_instance_of(Business).to receive(:type).and_return "Restaurant"

will return a "Restaurant" string whenever `business.type` is called.

In same way, you can make this method to return other values like "Bar" and check your `elsif` scenario.